# Cast or convert mongodb _id object to string in Logstash pipeline

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, logstash

I am working on creating a pipeline to get data from MongoDB to ElasticSearch using Logstash.
I am using dbschema mongodb jdbc drivers. I am able to connect to database using driver but I am facing issue with _id . As in MongoDB its of type object So I am getting issue with converter. Here is error I am getting.

```
Exception when executing JDBC query {:exception=>#<Sequel::DatabaseError: Java::OrgLogstash::MissingConverterException: Missing Converter handling for full class name=org.bson.types.ObjectId, simple name=ObjectId>}
```

My pipeline is as below :

```
input{
jdbc{
jdbc_driver_library => "C:/logstash-6.1.0/logstash-6.1.0/bin/driver/mongo/dbschema/mongojdbc1.2.jar"
jdbc_driver_class => "Java::com.dbschema.MongoJdbcDriver"
jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mongodb://abc.com:27017/test"
jdbc_user => ""
statement => "db.getCollection('Employee').find({})"
codec => json
}
}

output {
elasticsearch {
hosts => 'http://localhost:9200'
index => 'mongodbschema'
codec => json   
}
stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Is there any way I can convert/cast or do something in filter to change datatype of _id from object to string

Comment: Have you found solution ?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
statement => "db.getCollection('Employee').find({ },{'_id': false})"
```

Comment: Try and check statements are mostly part of the comments section and should not be an answer if you are not confident whether it will solve the problem or not. Once you have enough reputations you can add comments too. Please add comments instead of an answer in such cases.

Comment: What if I want ObjectId, like array = [ObjectId("5fa4eb465f1a33052bf16ec8")] - array of object ids?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in filter

```
filter {
mutate {
remove_field => [ "_id" ]
}}
```

Comment: "Try this" answers are discouraged on StackOverflow, please post an answer only if you are fairly confident it will work and include an explanation of why. Additionally, the OP is asking to cast or convert, not delete the `_id` field

Answer (score 0):

Since in elasticsearch `_id` is a reserved field (you can pass `_id` to index API in PUT operation to update a document), you must apply a filter that mutates the mongodb `_id`, for instance:

```js
filter {
  mutate {
    rename => [ "_id", "mongo_id" ]
  }
}
```